# Is there an xor (exclusive or) infix operator in TLA+?

Tags: tla+

Does TLA+ have an xor operator defined as part of the language itself, or do I have to define my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the assumption that `A \in BOOLEAN /\ B \in BOOLEAN`, what is known in propositional logic as "XOR" is inequality:

```
A # B
```

which under the same assumption is equivalent to `~ (A <=> B)`. When `A, B` take non-Boolean values, these two formulas are not necessarily equivalent. The following axiom could describe the operator `<=>`

```
THEOREM
    ASSUME
        /\ A \in BOOLEAN
        /\ B \in BOOLEAN
    PROVE
        (A <=> B)  =  (A = B)
```

For non-Boolean values of `A` and `B`, the value of `A <=> B` is not specified.
In the moderate interpretation of Boolean operators it is unspecified whether `A <=> B` takes non-Boolean values for non-Boolean `A` or `B`.
In the liberal interpretation of Boolean operators, `\A A, B:  (A <=> B) \in BOOLEAN`, as described in the [TLA Version 2: A Preliminary Guide](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/tla/tla2-guide.pdf).

See also page 10 (which defines the Boolean operators for Boolean values of the arguments) and Sec. 16.1.3 of the [TLA+ book](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2002/12/The-TLA-Language-and-Tools-for-Hardware-and-Software-Engineers-Book.pdf). The formula

```
(A \/ B) /\ ~ (A /\ B)
```

is meaningful also for non-Boolean values of the identifiers `A` and `B` (TLA+ is untyped). So

```
(15 \/ "a") /\ ~ (15 /\ "a")
```

is a possible value. I do not know if TLA+ specifies whether this formula has the same value as

```
15 # "a"
```

See also the comment on [Appendix A, Page 201, line 10 of Practical TLA+](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/tla/practical-tla.html).

Comment: Neat! I never considered that # is equivalent to xor over the set of Boolean values, but of course that's the case.

Comment: One (small) thing to keep in mind is that if A and B are not booleans but are the same type, `A /= B` is valid TLC but `(A \/ B) /\ ~(A /\ B)` is not.