# Difference between => and <=>

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, boolean-operations, tla+

I am learning TLA+ from [this great "Learn TLA+" page](https://learntla.com/tla/logic/).

I cannot get the *practical* difference between `=>` and `<=>`. I get it in terms of "truth table", but I cannot really *grasp* it.

Could one provide a practical TLA+ example highlighting the difference between those two?

Related:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68293/what-is-the-difference-between-only-if-and-iff

Comment: Somewhat relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46702774/1959808

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine we have a bounded queue `q` with max size `MAX`, a `reader` process that pops messages from the queue , a `writer` process that adds messages to the queue, and a `queue_maxed_flag` that is either true or false. Here's four possible invariants:

- `(len(q) = MAX) => queue_maxed_flag` means (in addition to other possible things, depending on the spec) that if a writer adds a message when `q` has `MAX-1` messages *it must also* **set** the `queue_maxed_flag`, otherwise the invariant is violated. However, if the reader pops from a maxed queue, it does not need to **unset** `queue_maxed_flag`.
- `queue_maxed_flag => (len(q) = MAX)` means (in addition to, etc) that if a reader pops a message when `q` has `MAX` messages *it must also* **unset** the `queue_maxed_flag`. However, if the writer adds a message when `q` has `MAX-1` messages, it does not need to **set** `queue_maxed_flag`.
- `(len(q) = MAX) <=> queue_maxed_flag` and `queue_maxed_flag <=> (len(q) = MAX)` mean the same thing: the prior two invariants both hold. If the writer writes the last message to a queue, it must set the flag, and if the reader reads from a full queue, it must unset the flag.

So why `A <=> B` and not `A = B`? `A <=> B` is stricter in that it expects both A and B to be booleans. TLC evaluates `5 = 6` as `FALSE`, but it raises an error on `5 <=> 6`.

Comment: An interesting point about `5 <=> 6`: it is *some* value, but we don't know *which* value, because we don't know whether `5 \in BOOLEAN` and `6 \in BOOLEAN` (the TLC error is `Error: Attempted to evaluate an expression of form P <=> Q when P or Q was not a boolean.`). Trying the expression `5 = TRUE` raises `Error: Attempted to check equality of integer 5 with non-integer: TRUE`. If it so happened that `5 = TRUE` and `6 = TRUE`, then `5 <=> 6` would equal `TRUE`, but (I think that) we cannot deduce this from the axiom in the module `Peano`.

Comment: The most relevant modules are [`Peano`](https://github.com/tlaplus/Examples/blob/522e59293a4c87d3dd1070af704f423725d48e04/specifications/SpecifyingSystems/Standard/Peano.tla) and [`ProtoReals`](https://github.com/tlaplus/Examples/blob/522e59293a4c87d3dd1070af704f423725d48e04/specifications/SpecifyingSystems/Standard/ProtoReals.tla).

Answer (score 4):

`=>` ("if") is an Implication. Here's an example:
**If the door opens, sound the alarm.** 
*Note that the alarm can still be triggered because of something other than the door opening (e.g. a window opening).*

Here's its truth table. Think you are programming an alarm system for a customer. `x` represents the door opening, `y` the alarm sounding.

```
x | y | x => y | Explanation
0 | 0 |   1    | The door doesn't open, the alarm doesn't sound (You don't want the alarm to go off for nothing)
0 | 1 |   1    | The door doesn't open, but the alarm still sounds (e.g. because a window was opened)
1 | 0 |   0    | The door opens, but the alarm doesn't sound (That is not how you want to protect your house)
1 | 1 |   1    | The door opens and the alarm sounds (What else would you have an alarm for)
```

Let's go to the Equation (`<=>` or "only if"). This is only true when both options are the same value. This example keeps the alarm but changes it to **Only if the door opens, sound the alarm.**
*Note: This time an opening window should not trigger the alarm, only the door should.*

```
x | y | x => y | Explanation
0 | 0 |   1    | The door doesn't open, the alarm doesn't sound
0 | 1 |   0    | The door doesn't open, the alarm sounds (That's a false positive, that window opening is not what your alarm should cover)
1 | 0 |   0    | The door opens, but the alarm doesn't sound (That is not how you want to protect your house)
1 | 1 |   1    | The door opens and the alarm sounds (What else would you have an alarm for)
```

This is something often mixed up and written wrongly in specifications (It also conveniently is a legal defense if you know it).

Comment: This is what I get (the truth table), but  I would like to see a difference in TLA spec between those operators. I don't see how it applies to "because a window was opened" (in TLA+ context).

Comment: In other words, I know the semantic difference, but I don't know how it practically translates to TLA+ context.

Comment: In TLA+, `0` and `1` are natural numbers. `TRUE` and `FALSE` are the Boolean constants (forming the set `BOOLEAN`). The symbol `->` is used differently than `=>` (which is implication), for example `[S -> R]` is the set of all functions with domain `S` that take values in the set `R`. The operator `<=>` is equivalence, but `<->` seems to be unavailable in TLA+ (see pp. 268--273 of the [TLA+ book](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2002/12/The-TLA-Language-and-Tools-for-Hardware-and-Software-Engineers-Book.pdf)).

Answer (score 3):

```
THEOREM TRUE = \A x:  (x \in {1, 2})  =>  (x \in {1, 2, 3})
```

in contrast to

```
THEOREM FALSE = \A x:  (x \in {1, 2})  <=> (x \in {1, 2, 3})
```

which does not hold, because `\E x:  (x \in {1, 2, 3})  /\  ~ (x \in {1, 2})` (namely `x = 3`).

The identifier `x` could represent which room the system is in.

The value of the expression `A <=> B` is defined for `A \in BOOLEAN /\ B \in BOOLEAN`.
For non-Boolean values of `A` and `B`, the meaning of the operator `<=>` is unspecified by TLA+.
With the moderate interpretation of Boolean operators, `A <=> B` may be non-Boolean for non-Boolean `A`, `B`.
With the liberal interpretation, `A <=> B` is Boolean-valued, though the value is unspecified for non-Boolean `A`, `B`.

Section 16.1.3 "Interpretations of Boolean Operators" on pages 296--297 and Section 1.1 "Propositional Logic" on pages 9--11 (in particular page 9) from [1] are the most relevant to what the operators `<=>` and `=>` mean.

[1] Leslie Lamport, ["Specifying systems"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2002/12/The-TLA-Language-and-Tools-for-Hardware-and-Software-Engineers-Book.pdf), Addison-Wesley, 2002